# How long does it take to hear the sound of a plane that travels at the speed of sound?

Tags: waves, kinematics, acoustics, speed

in our physics lessons we often learn how to calculate the time that sound of a plane that travels faster than sound takes to reach us using the Mach cone.

But can we use the same method to calculate the same value for a plane that travels as fast as sound?

Does it make a cone? I would be really grateful I f you could explain this with some examples.

Comment: the cone degenerates to something like a wall and no airplane will stay in this situation long. but the sound just needs the normal time  arriving with sound speed at your ear.

Comment: Exactly, like @trula said, the sound will travel with the same speed (one Mach) irrespective of the speed of the plane (at least as a first approximation 'cause the pressures very close to the cone are huge and high non-linearities take place there). Additionally, like trula said again, a plane wouldn't be able to remain at the tip of the cone for too long due to the concentration of high overpressure which would eventually "explode".